# RDF query as string

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am new to RDF and SPARQL. Recently I tried to query the data from turtle file, and want to put it in a list. But what I've got are bunch of 'rdflib.term.Literal'. How can I convert it to string that can be append into list?

```
query =f"""
    SELECT (STR(?goal) AS ?label)
    WHERE {{
        {sub} {predi} {obj} .
    }}"""

    g.query(query)

    try:
        return g.query(query).goal

    except:
        result = []
        for item in g.query(query):
            result.append(item.label)
            print(type(item.label))
        return result
```

> `Here is the code I made but it does not work.`

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx3US.png)

Comment: [documentation](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rdf_terms.html) as well as [code](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/rdflib/term.html#Literal) is online. Just call `toPython` or use good old `str` on the Python object

Comment: Hi I did tried str(item.label) and came out error. That's why I am confused...